# $('#myModal').modal('show'); is showing nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

hi ,
am building my project with django framework but i got this problem when i use $('#myModal').modal("show") method , when i open source code it's working but it's showing nothing on my website page , this is the html code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body text goes here.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this the js code

```
{% if error_connection == True %}
        <script>
            jQuery.noConflict();
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            var input_username=document.getElementById('username_input');
            var input_password=document.getElementById('password_input');
            input_username.style.borderColor='Red';
            input_password.style.borderColor='Red';
        </script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Put your code in text with code tags not with screenshots thanks

Comment: it's done now you got the code

Comment: You have some CSS or HTML problem. Hard to guess what it would be. Something conflicts. Inspect the element and look at the css and see what is hiding it.

Comment: If the modal div is no longer hidden, have you tried changing the z-index to see if it's not right behind another element?